# Replaced a regular copper tee by a push in tee

Tags: bathroom

I replaced a regular 3/4 Tee with a push in 3/4 to 3/4 top 1/2 and now I lost like 75% water pressure. I don't get water in the restroom...Help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need a lot more information to help you (e.g. what exactly are you talking about? do you have a picture?). Edit whatever you can into your question. Thanks!

Comment: If the ID is much smaller then flow is restricted

Comment: You say the old was a “regular  3/4 tee”, to me that means all branches were 3/4, if you replaced that with a tee that has a single outlet that is 1/2 then yes that is a serious flow restriction.